# Make shorter replace, splitting and conversion C#

Tags: c#, string, replace, converters, split

How can I make my code shorter? This is my input *(it are coordinates)*:

```
(51.01407864998378, 4.15557861328125)
```

I want the coordinates to split in two different variables.

here is my code:

```
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder(); // creation of stringbuilder

text.Append("(51.01407864998378, 4.15557861328125)"); //append my string
text.Replace("(", ""); // remove the round brackets and white space.
text.Replace(")", "");
text.Replace(" ", "");
text.Replace(",", "_"); //in europe we use a comma as separator for decimal numbers, not a point.
text.Replace(".", ",");

string[] parts = text.ToString().Split('_'); // splitting and convert it.

decimal lng = Convert.ToDecimal(parts[0]);
decimal lat = Convert.ToDecimal(parts[1]);
```

results are 51.01407864998378 in variable `lng` and 4.15557861328125 in `lat`.

Can anyone make this code shorter? I use C#.
Thanks

Comment: What are you *actually* trying to do? Simply extract the values?

Comment: tbh you only need lat/long to six decimal places. right now you are trying to bring accuracy to the atomic level, which is fairly useless.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, I need only to extract the values

Comment: also, why are you sending lat/long to this method in this format?

Comment: @user1666620: well I have a google map. when the user click on a location, there must be send a lat/long to the server. I save that coordinate temporary into a hidden field and now I go use it on the server. The coordinates are stored like that in my hidden field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to extract the values, the shortest way would be to use a regular expression, like

```
\((?<lon>\d+\.\d+),\s+(?<lat>\d+\.\d+)\)
```

By using named capture groups you can extract specific parts by name.

After that, you just need to parse the text specifying the InvariantCulture, to ensure `.` is used as the decimal separator eg:

```
var coordRegex=new Regex(@"\((?<lon>\d+\.\d+),\s+(?<lat>\d+\.\d+)\)");

var input = "(51.01407864998378, 4.15557861328125)";
var match = coordRegex.Match(input);

if (match.Success)
{
   var lonText=match.Groups["lon"].Value;
   var latText=match.Groups["lat"].Value;

   var lon=decimal.Parse(lonText,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
   var lat=decimal.Parse(latText,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

`Regex.Match` is thread safe which means you can create a single static Regex object and avoid rebuilding the object, eg:

```
static readonly Regex _coordRegex=new Regex(@"\((?<lon>\d+\.\d+),\s+(?<lat>\d+\.\d+)\)");
```

A regex is also much faster because it *avoids* generating temporary strings until you request a specific group using `Value`. Until that point, the `Match` object contains only pointers to the original string. This means that there are fewer object allocations, less memory pressure and fewer garbage collections.

This leads to significant performance gains when processing files with many coordinates. In such cases, most of a program's memory usage is due to the generated temporary objects.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with  regex.

```
var coord = "(51.01407864998378, 4.15557861328125)";
Match match = Regex.Match(coord, @"\(([\d]*.[\d]*),[^\d]*([\d]*.[\d]*)\)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
{
      decimal lng = Convert.ToDecimal(match.Groups[1].Value, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
      decimal lat = Convert.ToDecimal(match.Groups[2].Value, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));

      Console.WriteLine(lng);
      Console.WriteLine(lat);
}
```

**Results**

51.01407864998378

4.15557861328125

Comment: This is only half the answer. It's not enough to capture the *text*, you also have to parse the numbers ensuring `.` is used instead of `,` as the decimal separator

Comment: It's not part of the question, no one knows where the coordinats comes from and which culture the OP is, but especially for you I've added the parsing step to the answer.

Comment: The US locale is a bad choice, because it uses a unique date format. To ensure unambiguous parsing the preferred culture is `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`

Answer (score 0):

You can split more simply, and use `decimal.Parse` to not care about dots and commas:

```
string src = "(51.01407864998378, 4.15557861328125)";

var temp = src.Split(new[] { '(', ',', ')' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var lng = decimal.Parse(temp[0], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var lat = decimal.Parse(temp[1], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Why? It isn't *simpler* than a regex but it *does* generate a lot of temporary strings and is, as a consequence, slower. If you used this to parse a file of coordinates, there would be a significant performance hit, both due to the string generation and garbage collection.

Comment: @Panagiotis: It's a lot simpler than a regex, imo. And what makes you think that using a regex wouldn't create lots of temporary strings and other garbage? I haven't run any tests, but I would guess that this method is probably more efficient than your own answer (in terms of both speed and garbage generated).

Comment: I suggest you run the tests then. I discovered this by processing large files, when I found that splits caused memory usage to continuously increase. As for the explanation, it's in my answer and  the [.NET reference code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/regex/system/text/regularexpressions/RegexCapture.cs,98a52e6ee2014292). Regex doesn't split strings, it *parses* them, generating objects only for successful captures The captures contain only pointers to the input string